# align image item in materialize css

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using MaterializeCSS framework, I would like to align a picture in the right just next to the other items, I added the img tag to one of items but it get displayed just next to the logo not in the right side

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="index.html" class="brand-logo"> Logo</a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul class=" right hide-on-med-and-down">

     <li>  <a href=""> <img src="./img/bg.jpeg" alt="" style="width: 10%;"></a> </li>
       <li>  <a> username</a></li>
               <li> <a href=""> profile</a></li>

  </ul>
  <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use images of height 64px or under in materialize css Navbar, because navbar height is 64px . Or set height of 64px or under on img element.

```
<a href=""> <img src="./img/bg.jpeg"alt=""style="height:64px;">
```

To right align your navbar links, just add a right class to your  that contains them.

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="index.html" class="brand-logo"> Logo</a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i 
    class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
 <ul class=" right hide-on-med-and-down">
   <li>  <a href=""> <img src="./img/bg.jpeg" alt="" 
     style="height:64px;">
     </a> </li>
   <li>  <a> username</a></li>
   <li> <a href=""> profile</a></li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
   <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
   <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
   <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
   <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

[**Material CSS Navbar**](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html)